# How can I map a key combination to a character or modifier key in Windows 8?

Tags: autohotkey, keymap

I need to map Alt+e to é or to ´ (spanish accent). I read AutoHotKey may work but don't understand how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the Tutorial? https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s2
Alt is !, so Alt+e is `!e` so all you have to do is take the example and make it to what you want:

```
!e::Send é
```

Edit: so you wanted a "two key hotkey" - you could use the Input command like so:

```
$!e::
Input, OutputVar, T1 L1 ; this waits for a single key press and you can use if ... else for each key *
if (OutputVar = "e")
    Send é
else if (OutputVar = "i")
    Send í
Return

$!n::
Input, OutputVar, T1 L1
if (OutputVar = "n")
    Send ñ
Return
```

(*) Note that there are fancier techniques but by using an associative array for example but the above is pretty straight forward and easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I'm reading it now.
And is it possible to map alt+e to the accent? So I would type "alt+e + i" and I would get í (accented i).

Comment: Here I pasted code that will help to clarify my question:
http://p.ahkscript.org/?p=6383e215